# Use a .csv file as a reference to make multiple self-signed certificates

Tags: file, csv, batch-file, openssl, certificate

**I wanted to preface this with; I am not a coder**I am curious as to if I can take a Batch file I have that will generate a self signed certificate using OpenSSL and link it to a .CSV file to generate multiple certificates with a different file name. (My batch file also converts the .cer to .der as that is the format I need).

I.e

```
R001.der
R002.der
R123.der
```

My batch file does call another batch file that just references the directory of OpenSSL.

**My Batch File:**

```
setlocal enableextensions
@echo off
call vars.bat

echo #### Generating a new private key
openssl genrsa -out NewCertPrivKey.pem 2048

echo #### Converting private key to DER format
openssl rsa -in NewCertPrivKey.pem -inform PEM -out NewCertPrivKey.der -outform DER

echo #### Generating certificate request
openssl req -new -sha256 -key NewCertPrivKey.pem -out NewCertUnsigned.pem -days 3650

echo #### Signing the certificate request
openssl ca -verbose -days 3650 -out NewCertSigned.pem -keyfile demoCA\private\CAPrivKey.pem -cert demoCA\CACert.pem -infiles NewCertUnsigned.pem

echo #### Converting certificate to DER
openssl x509 -in NewCertSigned.pem -inform PEM -outform DER -out NewCertSigned.der

echo ##################################
echo The files to upload are NewCertSigned.der and NewCertPrivKey.der
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear. What is the content of the csv? (input) what do you want to achieve (output)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The contents of the .csv would simply have the names that I would want the files to be names and the subject information that the certificate requires. For example line 1 from A - G would look like this.

R001 US MA Hanscom TDC USAF 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you've omitted to clearly tell us the content of your `.csv` file, I'll assume your file is the `R001.der..` script you've included.

What you could do is (as a batch):

```
for /f %%a in (yourcsvfilename) do call yourbatchfileasposted.bat %%a
```

which will execute your batchfile delivering a parameter of the content of the first token (space-separated string) from each line of your `.csv` file.

**Note** Executing as a batch will mean not perpetually re-typing the command, but if you wish to make thing hard and re-type the command from the prompt, then reduce each `%%a` to `%a`. Note that the case of the `%a` **is** case-sensitive.

**AND** replace each `NewCertPrivKey`, `NewCertUnsigned`, `NewCertSigned` in the filenames used within your batch with `NewCertPrivKey%1`, `NewCertUnsigned%1`, `NewCertSigned%1` (ie. insert `%1` after the main filename-body.

This will create filenames like `NewCertPrivKeyR001.der.pem` when your batch is executed with a parameter of `R001.der` (%1 means `copy the first parameter verbatim`)

If you want `NewCertPrivKeyR001.pem` from a parameter of `R001.der` then use `%~n1` instead of `%1`. This uses the "name" part of parameter 1 - that is, the part preceding the final `.`

Note that your modified batch file will still operate as the original because if you don't supply a parameter when you run it, the `%1` is empty, so produces an empty string when copied.

Comment: My apologies for omitting the CSV file. The following is what it looks like:"

`line 1 from A - G would look like this. 
R001 US MA Hanscom TDC USAF 1.1.1.1`

And would continue increasing in number (R001, R002, etc)

So if I decided to do the `%~n1` command would I increase the number for each section of the excel?

Comment: Since column 1 of your `.CSV` contains (eg. `R001`) then the string delivered as the parameter to your revised batch would be `R001`. Since that is the desired string to be included, `%1` is all that is required (although in this case, `%~n1` would do the same thing as the value does not contain a `.`. The parameter delivered would be whatever is contained in column 1 on each line.

Comment: Thank you so much! that seems to work as it is generating multiple files.. another question, it seems to only pull from column "a", how do I get it to pull information from another column, like column "b"?

Comment: That's a function of the `for /f` command. Generally, `for /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=chars" %%a in (filename)` will use `c`,`h`,`a`,`r`,`s` as delimiter characters. Omitting the `delims=...` clause selects (comma,tab,space) as delimiters. The tokens (=columns/strings between delimiters) are then applied by number to the next-alphabetical `metavariable` ( *%%a* in this case ) so `tokens=1,2,3 ... %%a...` would assign the first column to `%%a`, second to `%%b` and third to `%%c`. `tokens=2,5,6 ... %%a...` would assign the second column to `%%a`, fifth to `%%b` and sixth to `%%c`.

Comment: You could then use `for...do exec1 %%a&exec2 %%b&exec3 %%c` where the `&` separates commands OR `for...do (exec1 %%a[newline]exec2 %%b[newline]exec3 %%c)` where each executablename and its parameters are on separate lines and the whole required-thingstodo is parenthesised. Oh - BTW, the modifiers clause(s) (tokens= and delims=) must be betweens rabbit's ears `"` - see `for /?` from the prompt for (terse) documentation.